# Can I make character hold hands using contraints?

Tags: animation, constraints

Trying to solve a problem here. I've got two characters, each with an already animated walk cycle. I want them to be holding hands:

[image]

I tried doing by hand but the result is too jerky:

[image]

Is there some way I can constrain the child's hand to the adult's to get a smooth result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, but it meets my needs for this project.

1. Created an Empty
2. Applied an Inverse Kinematics bone constraint to the hand bones of each character.
3. Set the empty as the target in the bone constraint and the chain length to 3.

This snaps the hands of each character to a single location. The chain length ensures that only the arms of each character move toward the empty.

[image]